# How would I calculate point values relative to the values of points nearest them?

Tags: qgis

I have a layer of points that numbers in the tens of thousands. Each point has an attribute field with values measuring level of magnitude. I would like to compare the attribute value of a given point to the points around it. In order to see how relatively high or low the point value is for a given area, the comparison will only include points within a given distance.

Example: I am focused on a point with a value of 10. There are three points close to this point with values 5,7, and 12. The calculation I would like to see would be [(10-5)+(10-7)+(10-12)]/3 for an average difference of 2. I would want to know if the average difference was a negative number.

I would like to do this for every point in the layer so some level of automation is pretty much mandatory. The platform I have available is QGIS.

I remember something similar in a past project where I converted points to a raster but have been unable to duplicate this as I used ArcGIS for that. I am not sure I have the appropriate tools in QGIS to undertake this project.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this with a combination of buffers with your given distance around each point. Don´t dissolve the buffers and you get the original values (names of your points, and values) also in the buffers.

Then you use from the processing tools - Qgis - vectoranalysis - count points in polygons (weighted) with your values as the weighted ones. This way you get the sum for you values. Then you use this layer again for counting points in polygons. Then you get the amount and value and can calculate the average in the field calculator (count*original value-weighted sum/count). Should end up with yourexample as (3*10 - (5+7+12)) / 3 = 2 . Hope i don´t overlooked something so the result should fit your idea, even if the calculations go a different way, they should be reciprocal.

If necessary you can join the table of this buffer-polygon to your original points.

Actually it would be even easier with the normal tool from the menu-vector-analysistools-point in polygons, but this don´t calculates the statistics, at least i always got problems with it.